# PyQt6 Slider not moving

Tags: python, pycharm, pyqt6, qslider

I'm having trouble with a horizontal slider in Python and PyQt6. I can't move the darn thing with my mouse. What could it be?

```
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QSlider
from PyQt6.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(800, 600)
        slider = QSlider(Qt.Orientation.Horizontal, self)
        slider.setGeometry(10, 480, 400,20)
        slider.setMinimum(0)
        slider.setMaximum(250)
        slider.setTickInterval(1)
        slider.valueChanged.connect(self.display)
        slider.setValue(0)
        widget = QWidget(slider)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    def display(self):
        print(self.sender().value())


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This should work right?
Is this a package problem?
I'm using PyCharm and Win11

I tried a lot of examples from google but nothing works

EDIT: I can move the slider with PageUP/Down buttons but not with the mouse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`widget = QWidget(slider)` is the culprit. I'm not sure what that is supposed to do.
You can set the slider as centralwidget directly and it will work fine (but look a bit weird)

Here's an example that puts the slider in a layout in a centralwidget. That may be more like what you intended to do.

```
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QSlider
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(800, 600)
        slider = QSlider(Qt.Orientation.Horizontal, self)
        slider.setGeometry(10, 480, 400, 20)
        slider.setMinimum(0)
        slider.setMaximum(250)
        slider.setTickInterval(1)
        slider.valueChanged.connect(self.display)
        slider.setValue(0)
        widget = QWidget()
        lay = QHBoxLayout(widget)
        lay.addWidget(slider)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    @staticmethod
    def display(value):
        print(value)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Thank you! It works now. So for future reference the slider needs to be in a layout? I'm a total beginner in Python and Qt and PyQt for that matter :) I do know you should arrange widgets in layouts but I had problems stacking multiple Labels on top of each other. So I dumped the layout and assigned fixed positions since this would run on a fixed size screen

Comment: @TadyTheFish I know that layouts may seem difficult in some circumstances, but it's only a matter of understanding them and getting more experienced. A common reaction is to avoid them, feeling that relying on fixed geometries would be fine; long story short: it isn't, so don't do it, as it's meant to fail sooner or later. I suggest you to take your time to go through the [documentation](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/layout.html) (including that related to each layout type), and look at tutorials (like [this](//realpython.com/python-pyqt-layout/) and [this](//www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/pyqt-layouts/)).

Comment: @TadyTheFish Also, use Qt Designer to do some experiments and get a better (and visually simpler) understanding of their mechanics. Start by reading the documentation about [using layouts in Designer](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/designer-layouts.html) and then do tests using basic layouts and different widget types (not all widgets behave the same within layouts, and their behavior depends on their size hints and size policies). If you still have problems achieving what you want, you can always ask a new question here on SO (after searching through existing ones).

Comment: Thank you for for the links i will read them and fix my project. I agree that not using layouts is a terrible idea.. I already made this priject in QT designer and c++. But I decuded to port everything to python so it it more cross platform. I had headaches when trying to cross compile for RPi and to use builroot. So now I want the same thing in Python and masve it will be easyer.. Who knows :)

Comment: Thanks again for the kick in the butt :) I rewrote everything so now I only use layouts ( no setGeometry). It took a combination of QVBoxLayout, QVHBoxLayout and QGridLayout to make it work :) THANK YOU